# How does Shutterfly differentiate the two links to render images of different sizes?

Tags: image, web-applications, thumbnails

I was looking at the thumbnail image in a Shutterfly rss feed and the link is

http://im1.shutterfly.com/procgtaserv/47a2d624b3127cce9854b08c5baa00000039100AYtWzNi4Yt2Qg

and this renders out a ~3KB thumbnail, as expected.

I compared it to the link to the image on the actual Shutterfly page, which has the same apparent link:

http://im1.shutterfly.com/procgtaserv/47a2d624b3127cce9854b08c5baa00000035100AYtWzNi4Yt2Qg

But when I click this link, it renders out a ~60KB image.

I've looked at this in Fiddler and Chrome Dev tools and can't see anything different in the requests that would tell the server what size to render.  I've even tried copying these links into Firefox to see if it was a browser/cookie type issue but they render differently there too.

I'm driving myself crazy trying to figure out what's going on.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two websites are different.

Thumbnail:
http://im1.shutterfly.com/procgtaserv/47a2d624b3127cce9854b08c5baa0000003**9**100AYtWzNi4Yt2Qg

Original:
http://im1.shutterfly.com/procgtaserv/47a2d624b3127cce9854b08c5baa0000003**5**100AYtWzNi4Yt2Qg

I opened both links in different tabs in Chrome.  Then, flipped back and forth between the two tabs, staring at the URLs.  There was a minor flash where the 9 changed to a 5, and vice versa.

Comment: Great eyes!  I had both links in Notepad and stared at them but missed that one character.  So much time wasted for something so obvious!  Thanks a million.